# How get certain values from an object and set it to a state in react useState

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, react-hooks, fullcalendar

I'm building a simple calendar using a **FullCalendar**. I'm trying to put two properties in my event calendar (service and date)
I have this sample array of object

```
const appointment = [
{ service: "Grooming", date: "2022-11-23", name: "Josh" },
{ service: "Vaccine", date: "2022-11-22", name: "Aaron" }];
```

I try to get service and date properties and put them in a state

```
const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
```

This is my attempt to do it

```
useEffect(() => {
      setEvents(prev =>[ ...prev, {start: appointment.date, title: appointment.service} ])
      console.log(events)
    }, []);
```

This is my App.js

```
 <div className="App">
      <FullCalendar 
         ref={calendarRef} 
         plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
         initialView="dayGridMonth"
       
        events={events}
        />
    </div>
```

(RESULT-Console): 4 Objects (All unidentified). I don't know why it rendered four and all unidentified. Here's my reference in codeSandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-dawn-ltorxe?file=/src/App.js